# OAuth2 out of band user authorization

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I would like to avoid password based authentication on my server as much as possible. To achieve this, I have considered using OAuth2 as a primary access mechanism, allowing viewing of member restricted content.

Now I would like for my users to be able to issue some form of grant to specific clients through ssh or other non-url based channels with strong authentification. These should then be provided to the client (for example the web interface of my website), where it is used to generate the access token as defined by OAuth2.

Here is what I mean

```
# E.g. In bash or any other client
$ ssh auth.example.com
[authorization code]

# Now in a web browser form at forums.example.com
# User enters the code
<input type="text">[authorization code]</input>

# Some redirects occur
# Now at forums.example.com with a valid OAuth2 access token
```

It looks to me as if this would be completely within the specification of OAuth2, no I wonder if there already exists a standard way to achieve the same (or a very similar) protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, OAuth2 does not define how one should authenticate with a site, only authorization. A spec like OpenID Connect defines authentication.

If you used OpenID Connect, you can redirect the user to authenticate with a provider, say google.com. This is effectively out of band since it is no longer your site where a user's passwords or entered. Furthermore if the provider uses ssl (which they should), I believe it is quite secure. If you have a confidential server, you can simply setup the provider to redirect directly to your server with an authorization code that you would exchange for tokens, and store in the user's session. Read more [here](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).